# Cycles Data Output for meshing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, scripting, procedural

I often wanted to visualize shader data in cycles differently, turning it into 3D mesh for printing.

So far, I think the idea of baking out cycles procedural texture is as a 2D image. Ideally there must be a way to see the data as is, maybe some kind of 3D voxel data output.

Is there a way to sample 2d or 3d data of whatever values generated in cycles as numbers? Can we do this using OSL or Python?